# Find a function $u(x,t)$ satisfying some initial conditions for a vibrating string of length $\pi$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

Solve the following problem for a vibrating string of length $π$: Find a function
$u(x, t), 0 ≤ x ≤ π, t ≥ 0$, satisfying

$∂^2u/dt^2 = ∂^2u/dx^2, 0 < x < π, t > 0$

the boundary conditions

$x(0, t) = x(π, t) = 0, t > 0,$

as well as the initial conditions

$u(x, 0) = \sin(2x), ∂u(x, 0)/∂t = −\sin(x) + \sin(3x), 0 ≤ x ≤ π$

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of the wave equation has the form $u(x,t)=f(x+t)+g(x-t)$. The boundary conditions require $0=f(t)+g(-t)$ and $0=f(\pi+t)+g(\pi-t)$ giving
$$
f(t)=-g(-t)=f(2\pi+t)
$$
Thus $f$ is a $2\pi$ periodic function and at $t=0$ one gets
\begin{align}
\sin(2x)=u(x,0)&=f(x)+g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)\\
−\sin(x)+\sin(3x)=u_t(x,0)&=f'(x)-g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(-x)
\end{align}
where the second equation can be integrated to 
$$
\cos(x)-\frac13\cos(3x)+C=f(x)+f(-x)\\
\sin(2x)+\cos(x)-\frac13\cos(3x)+C=2f(x)
$$
The integration constant $C$ cancels in $u(x,t)=f(x+t)-f(t-x)$.

Comment: How do you get f(2π+t) in f(t)=−g(−t)=f(2π+t)? And how can you simplify g(x)=-f(-x) in sin(2x)=u(x,0)=f(x)+g(x)=f(x)−f(−x)?

Comment: By replacing $t$ with $t+\pi$ in the second boundary condition. This supposes that instead on the interval, the wave equation is solved on all of $\Bbb R×\Bbb R_+$ so that the replacement and thus periodicity makes any sense. -- The symmetries of the function pair $f,g$ have to hold everywhere. I do not understand the question, it is simple substitution.